# Is there any 'open' Local Storage Adapter for Ember Data?

Tags: javascript, local-storage, ember.js

I am planning to use localstorage to keep the user data and to use Ember Data to manage this data for a personal web-app. I have read on the 'Ember Data' README.md that make a adapter for local storage is possible.

Is there any open implementation available? I am really new to GitHub and can't find any project with this type of adapter.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I've created a localStorage adapter that supports hasMany/belongsTo associations, its also got a pretty decent test suite:

https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter

Answer (score 7):

After have look throw all the branch of https://github.com/emberjs/data and I have found this https://github.com/thomasboyt/data/commit/249f60adbb80ec24a3e7739ce3892711588f7de4 , this is a localStorage adapter attempt by thomasboyt.

If you know any other attempt I would like to know them :-)